# Dir.glob not showing new device in same chef-client run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to mount a device and later in same chef-client run, I need to `Dir.glob('/dev/xvd?')` all the devices, but the file for the device I just mounted doesn't exist until the next chef run.

For clarity, my mount does happen correctly and I get no errors - I just can't see the device result from `Dir.glob` until the next chef-client run.

In this instance, `mount_point = /data` and `device_id = /dev/xvdf`

```
mount "#{mount_point}" do                                                        
    device device_id                                                             
    fstype 'ext4'                                                                
    options 'noatime,nobootwait'                                                 
    action [:enable, :mount]                                                     
end
```

If I try to get all the devices and log them out right after I utilize the [mount resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_mount.html), `/dev/xvdf` doesn't appear in the list.

```
devices = Dir.glob('/dev/xvd?')                                                                                                                  
devices.each do |device|                                                         
    log "devices available: #{device}"                                         
end
```

My log output appears as such. One line from the mount resource and only one line from my log output which is missing the new device `/dev/xvdf` and displays an existing device `/dev/xvda`

```
- mount /dev/xvdf to /data
* log[devices available: /dev/xvda] action write
```

** **UPDATE** **  Trying to reload ohai to get available devices.

```
ohai "reload_filesystem" do                                                      
  action :nothing                                                              
end                                                                              

# now we can enable and mount it and we're done!                                 
mount "#{mount_point}" do                                                        
  device device_id                                                             
  fstype 'ext4'                                                                
  options 'noatime,nobootwait'                                                 
  action [:enable, :mount]                                                     
  notifies :reload, "ohai[reload_filesystem]", :immediately                    
end                                                                              

log "***** testing ohai reload 1 ****"                                           
devices = Dir.glob('/dev/xvd?')                                                  
devcount = devices.count                                                         
log "devices count: #{devcount}"                                                 
devices.each do |d|                                                              
 log "devices available: #{d}"                                                   
end                                                                              

ohai "reload2" do                                                                
    action :reload                                                               
end                                                                              

log "***** testing ohai reload 2 ****"                                           
devices = Dir.glob('/dev/xvd?')                                                  
devcount = devices.count                                                         
log "devices count: #{devcount}"                                                 
devices.each do |d|                                                              
 log "devices available: #{d}"                                                   
end
```

** OUTPUT **

```
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * mount[/data] action mount                                       
xxx.xx.x.xxx     - mount /dev/xvdf to /data                                      
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * ohai[reload_filesystem] action reload/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.5.0/lib/ohai/plugins/solaris2/network.rb:57: warning: already initialized constant ETHERNET_ENCAPS
xxx.xx.x.xxx /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.5.0/lib/ohai/plugins/solaris2/network.rb:57: warning: previous definition of ETHERNET_ENCAPS was here
xxx.xx.x.xxx                                                                     
xxx.xx.x.xxx     - re-run ohai and merge results into node attributes            
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * log[***** testing ohai reload 1 ****] action write              
xxx.xx.x.xxx                                                                     
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * log[devices count: 1] action write                              
xxx.xx.x.xxx                                                                     
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * log[devices available: /dev/xvda] action write                  
xxx.xx.x.xxx                                                                     
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * ohai[reload2] action reload/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.5.0/lib/ohai/plugins/solaris2/network.rb:57: warning: already initialized constant ETHERNET_ENCAPS
xxx.xx.x.xxx /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.5.0/lib/ohai/plugins/solaris2/network.rb:57: warning: previous definition of ETHERNET_ENCAPS was here
xxx.xx.x.xxx                                                                     
xxx.xx.x.xxx     - re-run ohai and merge results into node attributes            
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * log[***** testing ohai reload 2 ****] action write              
xxx.xx.x.xxx                                                                     
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * log[devices count: 1] action write                              
xxx.xx.x.xxx                                                                     
xxx.xx.x.xxx   * log[devices available: /dev/xvda] action write
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hit by the two pass run [See this](http://docs.chef.io/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run) also named compile vs converge.

Chef does things in a certain order, it first compile the recipes to build a resource  collection (compile time), once that's done it execute the code for each resource to ensure it's in the desired state (converge time).

Your `Dir.glob` is in the recipe, when it's executed (at compile time) the mount resource has not been run and nothing was mounted.

You can embed your existing code into a [`ruby_block`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) resource so it will be run at convergence time and after the mount if it's later in the recipe code.

```
ruby_block 'List available devices' do 
  block do
    devices = Dir.glob('/dev/xvd?')                                                                                                                  
    devices.each do |device|                                                         
      Chef::Log.info("devices available: #{device}")                                        
    end
  end 
end
```

You can't use directly resources inside a `ruby_block`, that's why I used `Chef::Log.info` but the documentation has examples about it.

---

Update per comment:

Try this:

```
mount "/data" do 
  source "/dev/xvdf" # do whatever needs to be done there.
end

ohai "reload filsystem" do
  action :reload
  plugin "filesystem"
end

ruby_block "List filesystems" do
  block do
    node['filesystem'].each do |dev,properties|
      Chef::Log.warn("#{dev} is mounted on #{properties['mount']}")
    end
  end
end
```

This time I used the warn level, so you'll see something printed, if not try running with `chef-client -l info`

Comment: This didn't seem to work?  I wasn't able to see any devices and it was run after I had some available?  also, how would you take advantage of any variables derived inside this scope?  can I create a variable set to nil before and then set it to the correct device inside this ruby_block so I can use it after the block?  I did try that, but it also didn't work

Comment: All in all what you wish is to know the available devices, there's an ohai plugin for that, you just have to reload it after the mount. See [this](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ohai.html) and [this](http://docs.chef.io/ohai.html)

Comment: Is there a specific plugin you're referring to that enables this - I tried a few different ways to reload this - and I tried this before.  But I must be missing something b/c it still doesn't register any changes.  I've posted an update in my original question to show my changes and subsequent log output.  You can clearly see it does mount the filesystem to /dev/xvdf, but then it won't show that device when I try to find it in my dir.glob

Comment: Answer updated, your updated question is still hitting the problem explained on the first part of my answer, the log resources text are computed BEFORE your mount (BTW if there's nothing in /dev at start, I can't understand how you can mount it)